Paste data with formatting from one sheet to another
I would like to copy some tables from an Excel sheet containing several tables to another empty sheet. With all the copy and paste methods I use the same error message appears every time. These are cell sizes in the source tables that do not match the cells on the target sheet. The "Paste" method fails every time.
Sub Données_générales()

    Dim feuilleSource As Worksheet
    Dim derniereLigne As Long
    Dim debutTableauLigne As Long
    Dim nb_lignes_tableau As Long
    Dim nb_lignes_total As Long
    
    nb_lignes_total = 0
    
    Set feuilleSource = Workbooks("Indicateurs.xlsx").Sheets("Rapport1")
    
    Windows("Rapport2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Tableaux1").Select
    
    derniereLigne = 20

    For i = 2 To derniereLigne
    
        Dim numero_tableau As Double
        numero_tableau = Val(Cells(i, 4).Value)
    
        nb_lignes_tableau = Cells(i, 8).Value
        
        debutTableauLigne = feuilleSource.Columns(1).Find(numero_tableau, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
        
        feuilleSource.Rows(debutTableauLigne).Resize(nb_lignes_tableau).Copy
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Données").Activate
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Données").Cells(nb_lignes_total + 1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Données").Cells(nb_lignes_total + 1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        nb_lignes_total = nb_lignes_total + nb_lignes_tableau
    Next i
    
    
End Sub


If possible, avoid using merged cells in your sheet.

Always copy only what you need to paste. Here you copy the entire row and try to paste it from the second column. It doesn't have the right to fit.
Besides, after Application.CutCopyMode = False, the clipboard is cleared, so the next Paste will fail (there is nothing to paste).

Welcome Jessica! Read The Tour and earn your first badge! Please don't use CAPITALS!


Below code copies the entirerow(s)

feuilleSource.Rows(debutTableauLigne).Resize(nb_lignes_tableau).Copy


Below code tries to paste it to a cell on Sheets("Données"). But the cell is on Column B. There isn't enough space to paste the rows.
Try Cells(nb_lignes_total + 1, 1).

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Données").Cells(nb_lignes_total + 1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


The 2nd PasteSpecial raise runtime error 1004 because the 1st Application.CutCopyMode = False clean the clipboard. It's no way to paste w/o coping sth.. Remove that code line to fix it.

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Données").Cells(nb_lignes_total + 1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Données").Cells(nb_lignes_total + 1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False



It worth to read :

How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA
